# Adding dot (".") to end of url e.g. /index.php. shows code of the php file instead of executing it

Tags: php, apache, vagrant

I have the strange behaviour <strike>on one</strike> on all my projects (Laravel/xtcommerce shop), when I add a dot to the end of the URL (`www.url.com/index.php` --> `www.url.com/index.php.`) the php code is shown in the view rather then being executed. This behaviour only appears in my Vagrant Box. This works on every URL / PHP File. It's definetly not the .htacces file, which is leading to this bug. I don't know any approach, besides the htacces file, on how to tackle this problem. Is this maybe a known bug? 

If I can provide you with more information just let me know.


**Edit:**

The Vagrant uses an Apache webserver with following modules loaded:

 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 mpm_worker_module (shared)

**PHP Modules:**

apc
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

**Zend Modules:**

Xdebug


**Apache Config File:**

```
# ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName somesite.de

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/somesite"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for      /var/www/somesite/public

  <Directory "/var/www/somesite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Load additional static includes

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/somesite_http_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/somesite_http_access.log" combined

  ## Server aliases
  ServerAlias www.somesite.de

  ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
  SetEnv APP_ENV dev

  ## Custom fragment
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/somesite/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you specify what webserver you are using (Apache, nginx, ...) with which modules loaded ?

Comment: Also your configuration files for nginx/apache, etc.

Comment: where do you define your handler for php extension ? you must have something like `<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: I'm just gonna point out, that's a LOT of extensions you have enabled. Consider disabling the ones you don't need to improve overall performance ;)

Comment: Check the comment of Frederic Henri, I also think that is related to such issue (where the trailing `$` is omitted in your setup?).

Comment: @FredericHenri  I can't find this setting in my Vagrant Box

Comment: search for `.conf` file under `/etc/httpd` this file only configured a virtual host, its not the full configuration of apache

Comment: @FredericHenri What you mentioned in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334908/adding-dot-to-end-of-url-e-g-index-php-shows-code-of-the-php-file-inste?noredirect=1#comment52546363_32334908) is not in my apache2 config. Should it be there?

Comment: well I am not 1. php developer and 2. apache expert but it looks too minimalist, you do not load any module ? search or http.conf in your vm (default path is /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)